# Magento 2.3 - Admin create order customer grid add company name

Tags: magento2.3, adminhtml, order-grid

I want to add the company name to the customer grid, when you create a new order in the admin panel.

Therefore I created the following module, but there is no field with company name added to the grid.

What am I missing here?

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_customer_block.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.customer.grid.container">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">\Vendor\ Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.customer.grid.columnSet">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="company" after="billing_postcode">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Company</argument>
                    <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">company</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Customer/Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer;

class Collection extends \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection
{
    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->joinAttribute(
            'company',
            'customer_address/company',
            'default_billing',
            null,
            'left'
        );
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like my answer is identical to your code.... I have updated my module, so you are welcome to try my module. However, I admit I can't see any major difference. But my module does work on my local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> step 1: add your column into the ui_component file `sales_order_grid.xml`
>
> app/code/Mbs/CompanyName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="company" >
            <settings>
                <sortable>true</sortable>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Company</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

> step 2: create di.xml
>
> app/code/Mbs/CompanyName/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
            <plugin name="grid_order_company_name" type="Mbs\CompanyName\Plugin\JoinCompanyName" sortOrder="5" />
        </type>
    </config>
```

> step 3: create an admin plugin that feeds the column with the value from the sales_order_address table
>
> app/code/Mbs/CompanyName/Plugin/JoinCompanyName.php

```
<?php

namespace Mbs\CompanyName\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory;

class JoinCompanyName
{
    public function afterGetReport(
        CollectionFactory $subject,
        $collection,
        $requestName
    ) {
        if ($requestName == 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
            $select = $collection->getSelect();
            $select->joinLeft(
                ['customer_address' => $collection->getTable('sales_order_address')],
                'main_table.entity_id = customer_address.parent_id and address_type="billing"',
                ['company']
            );
        }
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Full module below:
https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/companyname/src/master/

Comment: Thanks Herve! That's nice, but not it is added to the sales order grid. But we need it at the create new order grid. That's the grid when you click the orange button create new order from the order grid.

Comment: looks like you were really close, <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">company</argument> should read <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">billing_company</argument>

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issues, we can separate the problem in 2 steps:

**step 1: make the column appearing**

create a new module and add the layout file `sales_order_create_customer_block.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>       
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.customer.grid.columnSet">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.customer.grid.columnSet.company" as="Company">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Company</argument>
                    <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">billing_company</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**step2: feed the column with data**
take over the collection that feed the column

insert the xml snippet

```
<referenceBlock name="adminhtml.customer.grid.container">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">Mbs\CompanyName\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
```

and then add the collection file

```
<?php

namespace Mbs\CompanyName\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer;

class Collection extends \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection
{
    /**
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection
     */
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->joinAttribute(
            'billing_company',
            'customer_address/company',
            'default_billing',
            null,
            'left'
        );

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just tried it again, and there is no company name field added to the admin, when clicking the create new order button. What am I missing here?